# Haskell multiple conditions of If

Tags: haskell, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

I am having problems with the following exercise:

Write a function that receives three Ints and sums them if they are all positive and returns 0 (zero) otherwise.

What I have done is the following:

```
sum' :: int -> int -> int -> int
sum' x y z = if x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0 then x+y+z else 0
```

I don't know how to make multiple conditions on an if, not sure if this is done with logical "connectors" (like `||` or `&&` in Java) or if it is done in a similar way to the code I wrote.

Comment: These are commonly referred to as "logical connectives" (in logic/maths) or "boolean operators" (in programming). Other names also are used, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done in multiple ways.

For example, using `&&`:

```
sum' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
sum' x y z = if x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 then x+y+z else 0
```

Or using `all` and a list:

```
sum' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
sum' x y z = if all (>= 0) xs then sum xs else 0
    where xs = [x, y, z]
```

Comment: So the  && || work in Haskell the same way they work in Java?
And i can use the where keyword without using guards?

Answer (score 4):

Or using guards, which would make it look almost exactly like the human version of the definition:

```
sum' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
sum' x y z 
    | x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 = x+y+z
    | otherwise = 0
```

On a side note, always remember that types start with a capital letter. In your case, your type signature should use "Int" instead of "int".

I hope this helps.